# It's possible to read an incoming call using java?

Tags: java, phone-call

I'm doing a DVT program (For a pizzeria) as test for the university in Java. I want that the program reads the incoming call from a telephone (Landline) but I don't know how.
I guess that the telephone should be connected to the PC and to the line, but I don't know what I need to do it. Do you know how can I do it or something similar?
I only need some reference or idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Java Telephony API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jtapi-136088.html) ? There's a [simple introduction here](http://blog.devrealm.org/2009/03/26/jtapi-overview/).

Comment: simple introduction link giving 404. can any one help with any other resources?